# Dominant 7th and Mixolydian

Tags: chords, chord-theory, harmony, modes

Is the mixolydian mode the same as the dominant 7th? I don't know how else to ask it - My grammar is very good!

Answer (score 8):

They are not the same, because the Mixolydian mode is a mode and the dominant 7th is a chord.

However, they are related. The G Mixolydian mode is `G A B C D E F`, and the G dominant 7th chord is `G B D F`, a subset of that Mixolydian mode.

This similarity is because the dominant 7th chord is built on the fifth scale degree of a major key. Similarly, the Mixolydian mode begins on the fifth scale degree of a major key (note that G Mixolydian has the same members as a C-major scale, and G is scale-degree 5 of C).

Part of the confusion is that jazz musicians can use a Mixolydian scale to improvise over a dominant 7th chord, and some musicians thus take that to mean the two are synonymous. They are similar, but not the same.

Comment: So I have got it nearly correct, except for the scales bit

Comment: Looks like it, yep. If you can clarify exactly why they are different but also why they're similar, then I'd say you've got it.

Comment: Yeah, I've actually learnt something today: Mixolydian Scales!

Comment: @Goodra - yes, except 'scales' that use the notes from a normal scale (Cmajor, Eb harmonic minor, F# melodic minor, etc. but have another note , not that root, as their base or home, are generally called *modes*.

Comment: @Tim , so is it appropriate to call it a scale or not?

Comment: I would say mode is more accurate. Wonder what Richard thinks.

Comment: You'll also hear people say things like "Mixolydian scale" (as I do in my final paragraph), but mode technically *is* more accurate.

Comment: Another case where nomenclature is confusing.  I would say that "modes" (which usually means the medieval European modes) are a subset of "scales" (which means any set of tones that are the basis of a particular piece of music).  Mixolydian is thus both a scale and a mode.  And definitely not a chord.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets check you know what a Mixolydian scale is. It is a scale whose root note is the 5th note. For example, a Mixolydian C Scale consists of `G A Bb C D E F G`. A Mixolydian G Scale is `D E F G A B C D`

A Dominant 7th scale is just essentially the same thing. They have the same definitions!

However, the Dominant 7th chord is incorrect. Mixolydian is a type of scale. Dominant 7th is a chord.

Comment: Although I would personally call those two scales the G and D Mixolydian scales, respectively, just because we tend to name scales based off of their initial pitch.

Comment: Umm, the first scale is G Dorian, not C Mixolydian. Same pitches, different starting point. Ditto, for the second scale: it's D Dorian, not G Mixolydian.